# How do I send form data to a link?

Tags: html, forms, fetch

I have a HTML page with a form, that has 2 inputs, an email, and a username. I want to pass these inputs to a node.js express server called `exampleserver.com` with fetch(). I have no problems with the server, however, I have problems with the form. Here is my html form:

```
    <h1 align="center">Form</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder ="person@email.com" id="email">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="person">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()" id="demo">Click Me</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var email = document.getElementById('email')
    var formattedemail = email.value.replace(/\./, '-') //periods dont work as a path in the express server, so this changes the period to a hyphen.
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    function myfunc() {
    let fetchRes = fetch("https://exampleserver.com/inputform/" + formattedemail + "/" + username.value);
        fetchRes.then(res =>
            res.json()).then(response => {
                console.log(response.status)
            })
    }
    </script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: is your api taking param in `key:value` pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine with [jsonplaceholder api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), make sure your API is working as expected.

```js
var email = document.getElementById('email')
var formattedemail = email.value.replace(/\./, '-') //periods dont work as a path in the express server, so this changes the period to a hyphen.
var username = document.getElementById('username');

function myfunc() {
  // temp data
  formattedemail = "todos";
  username.value = "1";
  
  let fetchRes = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" + formattedemail + "/" + username.value);
  fetchRes.then(res =>
    res.json()).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Form</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="person@email.com" id="email">
<br>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="person">
<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()" id="demo">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: When I test the API with fetch without including the form data or any other code, it works fine.

Comment: In that case either your API is not accepting the data or it's accepting the data in other format than you are sending.

Comment: Hey! The code works fine now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Done! Thank you!